# Странное поведение виджета Frame с менеджером геометрии grid()

Tags: python, tkinter

На мой взгляд представленные фрагменты кода по сути ни чем не отличаются но ведут себя по разному.
Кто нибудь может объяснить почему?

Данный код создаст окно 500*500 с кнопкой в центре.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
root = Tk()

frame = Frame(root, width=500, heigh=500).grid()
button = Button(frame, text="Button")
button.grid(row=0, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Здесь же будет создано окно под размер кнопки.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
root = Tk()

frame = Frame(root, width=500, heigh=500)
frame.grid()
button = Button(frame, text="Button")
button.grid(row=0, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во втором случае переменной `frame` вы присваиваете результат вызова метода `grid` класса `Frame`, что соответствует `None`. В первом же случае вы корректно сохраняете ссылку на `Frame`.

---

**UPD:** Разберём немного подробнее.

В этих двух примерах различаются только строчки с созданием `Frame` и вызовом метода `grid()`. Распишем все действия, которые в них производятся.

Вариант 1:

```
frame = Frame(root, width=500, heigh=500).grid()
```

1. Вызывается конструктор класса `Frame`, полученное значение сохраняется во временную переменную `frame_tmp`, которая недоступна для пользователя.
2. Производится вызов `frame_tmp.grid()`, результат которого равен `None`
3. Результат вызова (`None`) присваивается переменной `frame` (т. е. `frame = None`)

Вариант 2:

```
frame = Frame(root, width=500, heigh=500)
frame.grid()
```

1. Вызывается конструктор класса `Frame`, полученное значение сохраняется в переменную `frame`.
2. Производится вызов `frame.grid()`, результат которого равен `None`. Так как этот результат никому не присваивается, он просто забывается.

Дальнейший код отличается только тем, что в первом варианте `frame` будет содержать `None`, а во втором -- объект типа `Frame`. За счёт этого второй вариант и будет работать правильно.

Comment: Не могли бы вы объяснить подробнее? Я только сильнее запутался.
например почему соответствует `None`?

Comment: Потому что метод `grid` возвращает всегда `None`, а вы присваиваете результат вызова переменной `frame`

Comment: Это вы про первый пример? Ведь во втором я вызываю метод экземпляра и все.

Comment: @АртурЗенков Да, про первый. Я добавил подробное описание происходящего в ответе. Если остались ещё вопросы, пишите.